# How to get 256 color support in a login shell TTY?

Tags: linux, colors, console, tty

I want to experiment with a fully text-based environment, however, the only thing that is stopping me - is getting 256 colors so my Vim color schemes could work perfectly.

When I enter a TTY by pressing CTRL+ALT+number, and execute `tput colors`, I always get just `8`.

So, in order to get a usable text-only environment, I'd need to have the following questions answered:

1. How can I configure the TTY to support at least 256 colors? (more if possible)
2. How can I set the font, both family and size?
3. How can I change the color scheme of the TTY, as I can in GNOME Terminal?

Any other tips on using such an environment appreciated.

Comment: The noted answer makes not mention of how to configure 256 colors, or FBTerm (Frame Buffer Terminal) and TERM="fbterm" in one of the console startup scritps (eg /etc/profile)

Comment: I use the FBTerm technique in a login shell only on VT2, you just need to remember it uses _decimal_ values, _NOT_ hex-decimal, when setting color values, as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316878/solarized-colorscheme-in-fbterm/388587#388587